# Jquery: .css color overwriting :hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#dicks1").click(
                function(){
                $("header ul li").css("color", "#fff");
                $("#dicks1").css("color", "#ce0000");
            });
            $("#dicks2").click(
                function(){
                $("header ul li").css("color", "#fff");
                $("#dicks2").css("color", "#ce0000");
            });
            $("#dicks3").click(
                function(){
                $("header ul li").css("color", "#fff");
                $("#dicks3").css("color", "#ce0000");
            });

            });
            </script>
```

I am trying to make it so when I click an "li" it turns red and stays red unless another one is clicked, but the :hover on the li gets removed and it stays white instead of turning #111.

I tried another script with .hover and I tried an if statement but they both failed. Is there something I am missing here?

here is the page: http://web-owl.com/cockslam/

Comment: not clicking a url that looks like that. and your example code doesn't have any over states in it?

Comment: over states? What do you mean?

Comment: There is no occurrence of `:hover` in your code.

Comment: you need to read up on css ranking. Inline css will always overrule stylesheet rules.If you add some inline style, you need to remove it for your other css to take effect. One reason it is better to toggle a class instead

Comment: Ah I mean to hover I have in the style sheet. So li:hover {color:#111;} is getting destroy by jquery when I click I link; it makes it css("color", "#fff");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an `!important` declaration next to your hover rule:

```
li:hover{
    color:#111 !important;
}
```

That way it isn't overridden by the inline styles added by `.css`

Comment: Oh my goodness how could I have been so foolish! Many thanks! I completely forgotten about !important.